# Upcasting a template object on function parameter failed

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, upcasting

In the following simplified code I try something like this:

```
struct A{};
struct B : public A {};
void func(A &a) {}
B b;
func(b);
```

Typically this is working but in the following more complicated code it doesn't work.
I guess that I missing something on templates.

Why it is impossible to upcast from `DenseVector<container_reference<std::array<double, 25ull>>>` to `container_reference<std::array<double, 25ull> >&` ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <cassert>

using namespace std;


template<class C>
struct container_reference
{
    typedef typename C::iterator iterator;
    container_reference(iterator f, iterator e) : f(f), e(e) {}
    void swap(container_reference &c) { std::swap(*f, *(c.f)); /*...and more*/ }
    iterator f,e;
};

template<typename C>
struct DenseVector : public C { using C::C; };

template<typename C>
struct DenseMatrixRect
{
    typedef DenseVector<container_reference<C>> row_vector;
    row_vector row(unsigned int i)
    {
        auto it = container.begin() + i * width;
        return row_vector(it, it + width);
    }
    C container;
    unsigned int width;
};


int main() 
{
    DenseMatrixRect<std::array<double, 25>> m; m.width = 5;
    m.row(0).swap(m.row(1));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: _"it doesn't work"_ is pretty vague. How does it not work? Do you get a compiler error? Does it crash? Do you get the wrong values?

Comment: I complete the missing part. Cannot upcast `DenseVector<C> : public C` to `C`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code fails because you try to bind a **temporary** `container_reference` returned from `row` in your call to `swap`.

You simply forgot to bind a `const` reference and mark the method itself `const`:

```
void swap(const container_reference &c) const { std::swap(*f, *(c.f)); /*...and more*/ }
//        ^^^^^                         ^^^^^
```

Since you are only swapping the (non-const) content of `c` and not `c` itself, you don't need it to be modifyable. Although, it's worth to point out that this is a pretty unusual `swap` where both arguments are `const` because they are only placeholders to the real content that is swapped.

Comment: Because of `operator[](....) const` it is preferred this:
`void swap(container_reference &&c)`
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Give it a name, then it's an lvalue and the cast works:

```
auto x = m.row(1);
m.row(0).swap(x);
```

Another option would be to add a version of swap that takes temporaries:

```
void swap(container_reference &&c) { std::swap(*f, *(c.f)); /*...and more*/ }
```